# How to Implement multiple loaders in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I currently have a list fragment that loads a list of contacts from the ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI using the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.  I also have a sqlite table that has contacts that have been added manually into my app by the user, I am using a ContentProvider for my other table.

I would like to load both the sqlite table as well as the ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI using LoaderManager callbacks but I have not been able to find any examples as to how this can be done.

Is this even possible, can some one point me to an example of how to implement this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you supply a different `id` for each loader you want so that you can decipher between what loader is called

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);
getLoaderManager().initLoader(1,null,this);
```

then in your `onLoadFinished` just get the if of the loader that was called

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor arg1) {
    loader.getId()
    ....
}
```